# Message passing to chrome extension from local python

Tags: python, post, google-chrome-extension, get

I want send/receive data between Chrome Extension and Local Python.
like, python sends data and chrome extension listens 
Any Idea how to do?

Comment: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging

Comment: Can you give example of using HOST from python?

Comment: Examples are pretty findable in the net. Just use google.

Comment: I didnt find but I decided to use websockets, thank you for your short answer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to pass message to Chrome using python websockets. It is very vast (average 10ms) and easy to pass JSON data. Here is the example [Python websockets](https://websockets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intro.html#synchronization-example). I hope it will help in the future for developers who encounters this question.